# Make white background of image transparent in css

Tags: html, css

I have two images, one of which is a small icon that is superimposed over the first image. My icon has a white background, so when the icon is placed over the other image, we get this effect where a white square appears over the image.  Ideally, I do not want to display this white background on top of my other image. Is there is a CSS property I can apply to my icon to make its white background transparent?

Comment: You can make de background of the icon transparent with tools like Photoshop.

Comment: You can't do what you want with CSS, you have to use an image editing tool, as the previous commenter said.

Answer (score 205):

Actually there is a way although only currently supported on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. If the background color is white, you can add the CSS property:

```
mix-blend-mode: multiply;
```

You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Comment: @SteffiKeranRaniJ Checkout my answer below.
This technique is MAGIC and needs more visibility.

Comment: When I tried this, in some cases the image's parent element also had to have a background colour explicitly set. E.g. if the body background is red, but the image is in a div, then that div also needed an explicit red background for the blend mode to work.

Comment: It's not the effect you guys want to achieve, just very close to it. "Multiply" is a merge mode where pixel color values (of background and image layer) are inverse-multiplied; so that white * white = white, anyColor * white = anyColor, and anyColor * black = black. Therefore, if your icon has only black and white, this method will work (not with antialiased edges!), otherwise it will alter colors where both layers have something other than b/w. There's no such thing as "white-means-transparent" in commonly used merge modes.

Comment: @dkellner in principle given a translation is possible it should be possible to combine with other elements to focus just on the white colour

Answer (score 23):

## Opacitator

`mix-blend-mode` does work for some browsers, but we've found that it causes performance issues in chrome, *I have no idea why*.

A designer on my team came up with this genius hack, where you create a layer that is mostly transparent, but when it is laid over a white background, it's color will match the color of the surrounding background.

> The way this "magical" color is found; is by calculating how much darker each color axis should be for the amount of opacity removed. The formula for this is `255 - ( 255 - x ) / opacity`. The issue is: If the opacity is set too low the formula gives you negative numbers (which can't be used). If the opacity is too high, you'll get some coloring on the non-white portions of your image.
>    Initially we used a spreadsheet that would do the calculations and through manual trial and error we would find that Goldilox color.
>    Once we started using sass I realized that this can be accomplished with a binary search. So I created a sass function that does the work for us.

Check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/dovidweisz/e659d4e7cead1676c86c4f396e4d7b18) on [sassmeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/e659d4e7cead1676c86c4f396e4d7b18). Pass your background color in-to the `opacitator` function on line 56 of the sass-code. and use the generated rgba color in a div (or a pseudo element) to overlay the image.

I also created a [working example on codepen](https://codepen.io/dovidweisz/pen/PyyZbe?editors=1100).

Comment: This still has the problem in that it recolors the image. Say you have an image with a white background and a container with a green background. You want the white in the image to be transparent, so it shows as green, and the rest of the image to be normal. Is that even possible here?

Comment: @douglas-gaskell why don't you fork the codepen, and see for yourself?

Comment: Works like a charm. Even with https://github.com/scssphp/scssphp

Comment: This is some beautiful code. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 6):

As there is no reliable way to remove background with CSS, sharing a code snippet of how I did it with JS:

```
public async removeImageBackground(image) {
  const backgroundColor = { red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255 };
  const threshold = 10;

  const imageElement = new Image();
  imageElement.src = image;
  await new Promise(function(resolve) { imageElement.addEventListener('load', resolve); });

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = imageElement.naturalWidth;
  canvas.height = imageElement.naturalHeight;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(imageElement, 0, 0);
  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (var i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
    const red = imageData.data[i];
    const green = imageData.data[i + 1];
    const blue = imageData.data[i + 2];
    if (Math.abs(red - backgroundColor.red) < threshold &&
      Math.abs(green - backgroundColor.green) < threshold &&
      Math.abs(blue - backgroundColor.blue) < threshold) {
      imageData.data[i + 3] = 0;
    }
  }

  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  return canvas.toDataURL(`image/png`);
}
```

Comment: wow, nice, this is very impressive :D

Comment: Best solution so far !

Answer (score 2):

No. Not yet...

*It is getting very close to possible, though*. Check out this article about CSS Filters, an experiemental css feature, that is doing some things client-side that are neat.

[CSS Filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter)

Comment: CSS Filters are now On By Default in Firefox.

Comment: How do I use it to do what is asked?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a container for your image.
Then for the css of the container:

```
overflow:hidden; height: (depends on your image, then make it a smaller px); width:100%;
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you, this is the quickest trick. You saved me hours of work!

Comment: This only works if the white background is around a square thing inside the image