# How to resize image without filling background with color

Tags: php, image, image-processing, jpeg, opencart

I have one problem while converting JPEG images in PHP.

**What I'm doing**

I have different image formats, and I need to resize them according to the container where it will be used, such as in a slideshow.

To be honest, this is default implementation of OpenCart engine. What is wrong with this?

When I resize a PNG everything work perfectly, and I get a transparent background.

But when I am converting JPEG images I am getting a background, by default rectangle is filled with white color. I understand that it is not possible to have JPEG with transparency.

**The result I want**

I want to resize JPEG images and composite them onto a transparent background. For example, convert and resize JPEG, draw transparent rectangle, put JPEG onto this rectangle and save it into PNG or another format which allows transparency.

Here is the code:

```
$image_old = $this->image;
$this->image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

if (isset($this->info['mime']) && $this->info['mime'] == 'image/png') {     
    imagealphablending($this->image, false);
    imagesavealpha($this->image, true);
    $background = imagecolorallocatealpha($this->image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
    imagecolortransparent($this->image, $background);
} else {
    $background = imagecolorallocate($this->image, 255, 255, 255);
}

imagefilledrectangle($this->image, 0, 0, $width, $height, $background);

imagecopyresampled($this->image, $image_old, $xpos, $ypos, 0, 0, 
    $new_width, $new_height, $this->info['width'], $this->info['height']);
imagedestroy($image_old);
```

I have tried to search for solutions, read manuals and documentation, but all my attempts failed. (black background, bad quality but still filled background)

Please help to get desired result.
Thanks everyone for help and advices.

Comment: You can just resize the image with css, can't you?

Comment: The issue is the JPEG was never transparent to begin with, so it will never be possible to get it with a transparent background. You could perhaps try to figure out the background color and try to replace that color with some obscure color and make that transparent ... however it will look pretty bad since the edges won't be anti-aliased or blended properly.

Comment: There is no way just to merge JPEG (not transparent ) with transparent PNG and get transparent PNG or GIF ?

Comment: `@user4836275`. Your statement is not true. You can just add a transparent border to a JPG and save as PNG in ImageMagick. `convert image.jpg -bordercolor none -border 20 image.png` The result will be transparent for 20 pixels outside the region of the original jpg.

Comment: You could use CSS to make white pixels transparent: see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34297963/273403

Answer (score 4):

```
    if(isset($_GET["path"]) && $_GET["path"] != "" && file_exists($_GET["path"])){

        $path = $_GET["path"];
        //getting extension type (jpg, png, etc)
        $type = explode(".", $path);
        $ext = strtolower($type[sizeof($type)-1]);
        $ext = (!in_array($ext, array("jpeg","png","gif"))) ? "jpeg" : $ext;

        //get image size
        $size = getimagesize($path);
        $width = $size[0];
        $height = $size[1];

        //get source image
        $func = "imagecreatefrom".$ext;
        $source = $func($path);

        //setting default values

        $new_width = $width;
        $new_height = $height;
        $k_w = 1;
        $k_h = 1;
        $dst_x =0;
        $dst_y =0;
        $src_x =0;
        $src_y =0;

        //selecting width and height
        if(!isset ($_GET["width"]) && !isset ($_GET["height"]))
        {
            $new_height = $height;
            $new_width = $width;
        }
        else if(!isset ($_GET["width"]))
        {
            $new_height = $_GET["height"];
            $new_width = ($width*$_GET["height"])/$height;
        }
        else if(!isset ($_GET["height"]))
        {
            $new_height = ($height*$_GET["width"])/$width;
            $new_width = $_GET["width"];
        }
        else
        {
            $new_width = $_GET["width"];
            $new_height = $_GET["height"];
        }

        //secelcting_offsets

        if($new_width>$width )//by width
        {
            $dst_x = ($new_width-$width)/2;
        }
        if($new_height>$height)//by height
        {
            $dst_y = ($new_height-$height)/2;
        }
        if( $new_width<$width || $new_height<$height )
        {
            $k_w = $new_width/$width;
            $k_h = $new_height/$height;

            if($new_height>$height)
            {
                $src_x  = ($width-$new_width)/2;
            }
            else if ($new_width>$width)
            {
                    $src_y  = ($height-$new_height)/2;
            }
            else
            {
                if($k_h>$k_w)
                {
                    $src_x = round(($width-($new_width/$k_h))/2);
                }
                else
                {
                    $src_y = round(($height-($new_height/$k_w))/2);
                }
            }
        }
        $output = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height);

        //to preserve PNG transparency
        if($ext == "png")
        {
            //saving all full alpha channel information
            imagesavealpha($output, true);
            //setting completely transparent color
            $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($output, 0, 0, 0, 127);
            //filling created image with transparent color
            imagefill($output, 0, 0, $transparent);
        }

        imagecopyresampled( $output, $source,  $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, 
                        $new_width-2*$dst_x, $new_height-2*$dst_y, 
                        $width-2*$src_x, $height-2*$src_y);
        //free resources
        ImageDestroy($source);

        //output image
        header('Content-Type: image/'.$ext);
        $func = "image".$ext;
        $func($output); 

        //free resources
        ImageDestroy($output);
    }
```

Try this one

Answer (score 0):

You can use the imagemagick to get it.

Resize image without black border, you can do it like this:

`convert in.jpg -resize 800x572 -background white -alpha remove -bordercolor black out.jpg`