# How to use css to change pixels of a certain color in an image?

Tags: css

Is there a way to take an image with a white background, and with css, take every pixel of white and change it's opacity to 0?

Basically, I want to take an image with a white background and get rid of the background, so it looks like a properly cropped image.  (Does that make sense?)

Extra credit:  Is there a way to declare a tolerance?  So, any color that is less than x number of variables away?  So, if rgb(150, 150, 150) was targeted, could we somehow capture all colors that are only a total of 30 values different, like rgb(140, 160, 160)?

Comment: You can't do it. With css you can only change the [filters](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662759/make-white-background-of-image-transparent-in-css

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in CSS but you can do it using photo editing tool like Adobe photoshop. Normally, you can export the image into .png instead of .jpeg so that it can have transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I think @simran is on the money here. The closest you would get is to use the CSS [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) property. Just be mindful it isn't supported by ie or edge [mix-blend-mode support](https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode)